# Dell Dimension 2400 problem

Tags: boot, troubleshooting, fan, dell-dimension

I have a new problem with a Dell Dimension 2400 PC. Until yesterday or the day before, it was working fine, but today when I press the power button the light on the power button turns yellow instead of green, the fan behind the processor increases speed until it sounds like a jet engine, and the computer does not boot up. I cleaned out the dust in the computer so that is not the problem. Also, the fan was blowing cold air. Do any of you know what might be causing this and how I might be able to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

First try this: [No Power, No POST, No Video](http://support.dell.com/support/topics/global.aspx/support/dsn/en/tree?c=us&l=en&s=gen&journalid=&treeid=011360B8243248349C306481A954B356&Query=&SystemID=&ServiceTag=&contenttype=&os=&component=&lang=&doclang=en&toggle=&dl=false). Also have a look at this: [Diagnostic Lights](http://support.dell.com/support/edocs/systems/dim2400/en/sm_en/advtshoo.htm).

If I remember correctly this is usually a power supply issue. Try opening the case and checking all the power connectors are properly connected.

Power supplies (PSUs) are relatively cheap so it might be worth buying one to test it. You will need to make sure the PSU has sufficient molex connectors, (these have 4 sockets on each plug), instead of the more common SATA connectors.

[How to replace the power supply on Dell Dimension 2400](http://support.dell.com/support/edocs/systems/dim2400/en/sm_en/power.htm)

Answer (score 0):

disconnect the power, press the power button (to discharge all components completely), reconnect power and try again.

if this doesn't help, open the case and carefully re-seat memory modules, add-on cards and connector cables.

Answer (score 0):

Neither the power supply nor any particular component attached to the motherboard seemed to be at fault, and reseating everything did not help, so I concluded that it was a motherboard or CPU problem.